# Overlapping and non-overlapping intervals into continuous ones

Tags: sql, oracle

I am starter in DB world and I am working with ORACLE DB and have specific problem that I cannot find any sufficient explanation on net.

I have table that has column (VALID_FROM (date) VALID_UNTIL (date) and COUNT (number))
The VALID FROM is mandatory while VALID_UNTIL is nullable (infinity lets say) and I want to get all intervals (they can overlap and they don't need to overlap) and make them into their respective non overlapping intervals (and sum all count in nonoverlapping intervals)

This is example of input and output that is correct:
Input:

| VALID FROM | VALID UNTIL | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 01/10/2022 | 11 |
| 01/01/2023 | NULL | 1 |
| 01/10/2023 | 19/10/2023 | 2 |
| 03/10/2023 | 12/10/2023 | 5 |

Output:

| VALID FROM | VALID UNTIL | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 01/10/2022 | 11 |
| 1.1.23 | 30.9.23 | 1 |
| 1.10.23 | 2.10.23 | 3 |
| 3.10.23 | 12.10.23 | 8 |
| 13.10.23 | 19.10.23 | 3 |
| 20.10.23 | NULL | 1 |

what is the most efficient query to achieve this and how this is by far toughest thing I tried to learn.
periods are nightmare.
Thank you

I have tried recursive, cte and did not get any results

Comment: This is advanced data processing already. I personally wouldn't want to do this in SQL, but rather leave it to the application. For the SQL, though: ordering by `valid_from` will make this task easier in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without the need for row-generators, self-joins or aggregation.

Unpivot the dates so that you have them in a single column and then use analytic functions to generate a running total of the counts adding the value when you get to a "from" date and subtracting the value when you get an "until" date. Then you can use the `LEAD` analytic function to find the next date, which becomes the `valid_until` value for the range and adjusted by a day if the new `valid_from` is an "until" value or if the `valid_until` is a "from" value:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT dt AS valid_from,
         LEAD(dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt)
           - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS valid_until,
         SUM(count*type) OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS count
  FROM   (
    SELECT valid_from,
           valid_until + INTERVAL '1' DAY AS valid_until,
           count
    FROM   table_name
  )
  UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS (
    dt FOR type IN (
      valid_from  AS 1,
      valid_until AS -1
    )
  )
)
WHERE  count > 0
AND    (valid_from <= valid_until OR valid_until IS NULL);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (VALID_FROM, VALID_UNTIL, COUNT) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-10-01', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-01', DATE '2022-10-02', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-10-03', DATE '2022-10-04', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-01-01', NULL,               1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-10-01', DATE '2023-10-19',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-10-03', DATE '2023-10-12',  5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALID_FROM | VALID_UNTIL | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-09-30 23:59:59 | 11 |
| 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | 2022-10-01 23:59:59 | 22 |
| 2022-10-02 00:00:00 | 2022-10-02 23:59:59 | 11 |
| 2022-10-03 00:00:00 | 2022-10-04 23:59:59 | 11 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-09-30 23:59:59 | 1 |
| 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 2023-10-02 23:59:59 | 3 |
| 2023-10-03 00:00:00 | 2023-10-12 23:59:59 | 8 |
| 2023-10-13 00:00:00 | 2023-10-19 23:59:59 | 3 |
| 2023-10-20 00:00:00 | *null* | 1 |

*Note: If you just want the start of each day then change `SELECT *` to `SELECT valid_from, TRUNC(valid_until) AS valid_until, count`.*

---

If you want to merge contiguous ranges with identical counts then you can pass the output to `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT dt AS valid_from,
         LEAD(dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt)
           - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS valid_until,
         SUM(count*type) OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS count
  FROM   (
    SELECT valid_from,
           valid_until + INTERVAL '1' DAY AS valid_until,
           count
    FROM   table_name
  )
  UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS (
    dt FOR type IN (
      valid_from  AS 1,
      valid_until AS -1
    )
  )
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY valid_from
  MEASURES
    FIRST(valid_from) AS valid_from,
    LAST(valid_until) AS valid_until,
    FIRST(count) AS count
  PATTERN (first_row same*)
  DEFINE
    same AS  FIRST(count) = count
         AND PREV(valid_until) + INTERVAL '1' SECOND = valid_from
)
WHERE  count > 0;
```

Outputs:

| VALID_FROM | VALID_UNTIL | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-09-30 23:59:59 | 11 |
| 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | 2022-10-01 23:59:59 | 22 |
| 2022-10-02 00:00:00 | 2022-10-04 23:59:59 | 11 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-09-30 23:59:59 | 1 |
| 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 2023-10-02 23:59:59 | 3 |
| 2023-10-03 00:00:00 | 2023-10-12 23:59:59 | 8 |
| 2023-10-13 00:00:00 | 2023-10-19 23:59:59 | 3 |
| 2023-10-20 00:00:00 | *null* | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jdppZcme)

Comment: I very much like the efficiency of your solution, but it doesn't produce the same results as mine under certain circumstances - see https://dbfiddle.uk/cQsNnY8Q. I guess it depends on what OP wants to see if there are two consecutive groups with the same count, or slightly overlapping with the same count.

Comment: I mean this works for all of mine inputs. @Boneist if you can tell me in which cases this is not working

Comment: @indexeddbidiot Updated for ranges overlapping on the end and start date only (and to be explicit about the times ranges are valid to as well as the days).

Comment: @indexeddbidiot the two scenarios that didn't work the same way as my solution were if there was a second row with the same count, but where the valid_from of the second date was the same as the valid_until of the first row - i.e. overlapping by a day (which MT0 has since fixed), and where the second row with the same count has the subsequent day - my solution combined the two into a single group, MT0's solution leaves them as two separate (but consecutive) groups - see https://dbfiddle.uk/v5TfO8ZA. It's up to you if you're ok with 2 groups in that case, or if they should collapse into 1 group

Comment: @Boneist There is a solution for that too.

Comment: @MT0 of course! Just takes away a bit from the efficiency of your original solution :( And the OP may well be ok with having the two rows split out anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient method - you're right in that overlapping time periods is hard! - but it should work:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT to_date('01/01/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('01/10/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, 11 cnt FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('01/01/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, NULL valid_to, 1 cnt FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('01/10/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('19/10/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, 2 cnt FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT to_date('03/10/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('12/10/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, 5 cnt FROM dual),
  list_of_dates AS (SELECT min_date + LEVEL - 1 dt, max_date, null_valid_to_present
                    FROM   (SELECT MIN(valid_from) min_date, GREATEST(MAX(valid_from), MAX(valid_to)) + 1 max_date, MAX(CASE WHEN valid_to IS NULL THEN 'Y' END) null_valid_to_present
                            FROM   your_table)
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (max_date - min_date) + 1),
       grp_info AS (SELECT dts.dt,
                           dts.max_date,
                           dts.null_valid_to_present,
                           SUM(yt.cnt) cnt,
                           dt - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY SUM(yt.cnt) ORDER BY dt) grp
                    FROM   list_of_dates dts
                           INNER JOIN your_table yt ON dts.dt >= yt.valid_from
                                                            AND dts.dt <= COALESCE(yt.valid_to, dts.dt + 1)
                    GROUP BY dts.dt,
                             dts.max_date,
                             dts.null_valid_to_present)
SELECT MIN(dt) valid_from,
       CASE WHEN null_valid_to_present = 'Y' AND MIN(dt) = max_date THEN NULL ELSE MAX(dt) END valid_to,
       cnt
FROM   grp_info
GROUP BY cnt, grp, max_date, null_valid_to_present
ORDER BY MIN(dt);

VALID_FROM  VALID_TO           CNT
----------- ----------- ----------
01/01/2022  01/10/2022          11
01/01/2023  30/09/2023           1
01/10/2023  02/10/2023           3
03/10/2023  12/10/2023           8
13/10/2023  19/10/2023           3
20/10/2023                       1
```

First, we work out the list of dates between the lowest available valid_from date in the data set (this assumes the valid_to date is never before the valid_from date), and the highest date, to which we add 1 (to account for rows where the valid_to is null), then we inner join the original data set to this list of dates.

Next, we use a technique called `tabibitosan` to generate a group identifier for each row. This works by subtracting the row number within the group of the cnt ordered by dt from the corresponding dt of the row. Rows that are consecutive and have the same cnt value will end up with the same difference value, otherwise the difference value will change.

Finally, we use the group identifier to group the final output, along with some jiggery-pokery to output NULL if there was a NULL valid_to date in the original data set.

Answer (score 1):

This may also not be terribly efficient; it hits the table multiple times, but doesn't expand the date ranges, so may be better or worse than @boneist's approach.

First work out all the period start dates, based on the real rows and implied ones from the overlapping to-dates:

```
-- real rows
select valid_from, valid_until
from your_table
union all
-- implied rows based on previous valid_until which overlaps
select valid_until + 1, valid_until
from your_table t1
where valid_until is not null
and exists
(
  select null from your_table t2
  where t2.id != t1.id
  and t2.valid_from <= t1.valid_from
  and t2.valid_until >= t1.valid_until
)
union all
-- implied row to replace open-ended row, if there is one
select valid_until + 1, null
from your_table t1
where valid_until is not null
and exists
(
  select null
  from your_table t2
  where t2.valid_from < t1.valid_from
  and t2.valid_until is null
)
and not exists
(
  select null
  from your_table t2
  where t2.valid_until > t1.valid_until
)
order by valid_from, valid_until
```

| VALID_FROM | VALID_UNTIL |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-10-01 |
| 2023-01-01 | *null* |
| 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-19 |
| 2023-10-03 | 2023-10-12 |
| 2023-10-13 | 2023-10-12 |
| 2023-10-20 | *null* |

I've added an ID column to your table as a way to avoid rows matching themselves in the `exist` clauses. If you don't have a unique identifier then you might be able to use `valid_from` and `valid_to`, as long as the combinations are unique.

Then work out the effective until-date for each of those from-dates, based on the surrounding rows, using the previous query as a CTE:

```
with cte1 (valid_from, valid_until) as
(
  -- previous query, omitted for brevity
)
select valid_from,
  case when valid_until is null
         or lead(valid_from) over (order by valid_from)
              <= max(valid_until) over (order by valid_from) + 1
       then lead(valid_from) over (order by valid_from) - 1
       else valid_until
  end as valid_until
from cte1
order by valid_from, valid_until
```

| VALID_FROM | VALID_UNTIL |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-10-01 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-09-30 |
| 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-02 |
| 2023-10-03 | 2023-10-12 |
| 2023-10-13 | 2023-10-19 |
| 2023-10-20 | *null* |

Then use that, as another CTE, and join back to the real data to get and sum the matching counts:

```
with cte1 (valid_from, valid_until) as
(
  -- previous query, omitted for brevity
),
cte2 (valid_from, valid_until) as
(
  -- previous query, omitted for brevity
)
select cte2.valid_from, cte2.valid_until, sum(t.cnt) as cnt
from cte2
join your_table t
on t.valid_from <= cte2.valid_from
and (t.valid_until is null or t.valid_until >= cte2.valid_until)
group by cte2.valid_from, cte2.valid_until
order by cte2.valid_from, cte2.valid_until
```

or in full:

```
with cte1 (valid_from, valid_until) as
(
  select valid_from, valid_until
  from your_table
  union all
  select valid_until + 1, valid_until
  from your_table t1
  where valid_until is not null
  and exists
  (
    select null
    from your_table t2 
    where t2.id != t1.id
    and t2.valid_from <= t1.valid_from
    and t2.valid_until >= t1.valid_until
  )
  union all
  select valid_until + 1, null
  from your_table t1
  where valid_until is not null
  and exists
  (
    select null
    from your_table t2
    where t2.valid_from < t1.valid_from
    and t2.valid_until is null
  )
  and not exists
  (
    select null
    from your_table t2
    where t2.valid_until > t1.valid_until
  )
),
cte2 (valid_from, valid_until) as
(
  select valid_from,
    case when valid_until is null
           or lead(valid_from) over (order by valid_from)
                <= max(valid_until) over (order by valid_from) + 1
         then lead(valid_from) over (order by valid_from) - 1
         else valid_until
    end as valid_until
  from cte1
)
select cte2.valid_from, cte2.valid_until, sum(t.cnt) as cnt
from cte2
join your_table t
on t.valid_from <= cte2.valid_from
and (t.valid_until is null or t.valid_until >= cte2.valid_until)
group by cte2.valid_from, cte2.valid_until
order by cte2.valid_from, cte2.valid_until
```

| VALID_FROM | VALID_UNTIL | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-10-01 | 11 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-09-30 | 1 |
| 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-02 | 3 |
| 2023-10-03 | 2023-10-12 | 8 |
| 2023-10-13 | 2023-10-19 | 3 |
| 2023-10-20 | *null* | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9OBwCCkh) with some extra queries showig some of the working.

Comment: While I appreciate the tick, you asked "what is the most efficient query to achieve this" - I imagine MT0's answer is (probably significantly) more efficient than mine, as well as being much much shorter and easier to maintain *8-)

Comment: Thank you for your help, There is just a small problem when I have multiple records with same VALID_FROM and VALID_UNTIL i get row for every that value.
I need 1 record if they have same FROM and UNTIL. But thank you very much you gave me a perspective on how to approach this problem from multiple levels.

https://pasteboard.co/409FHrDJ1aQU.png

With slight tweaks i believe it is possible to get same output as @MT0

Comment: sorry the tick was misplaced :)

Answer (score 0):

I may be easier if you prepare the list of possible intervals and test the intersections:

```
WITH data(id, valid_from, valid_until, cnt) as (
        select 1, to_date('01/01/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('01/10/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 11 from dual union all
        select 2, to_date('01/01/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), NULL, 1 from dual union all
        select 3, to_date('01/10/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('19/10/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 2 from dual union all
        select 4, to_date('03/10/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('12/10/2023', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 5 from dual -- union all
    ),
    allintervals as (
        select * from (
            select dat as date_from, lead(dat) over(order by dat, pos) as date_until from 
            (
                select 2 - mod(row_number() over(order by dat),2) as pos, dat from 
                (
                    select valid_from as dat from data
                    union
                    select nvl(valid_until, to_date('31/12/2999','dd/mm/yyyy')) from data
                )
            )
        )
        where date_until is not null
    )
    select date_from, nullif(date_until,to_date('31/12/2999','dd/mm/yyyy')) as date_until, sum(cnt) as cnt 
    from data d
    join allintervals ai on 
        d.valid_from < ai.date_until 
        and
        nvl(d.valid_until, to_date('31/12/2999','dd/mm/yyyy')) > ai.date_from
    group by date_from, date_until
    ;


01/01/2022  01/10/2022  11
01/01/2023  01/10/2023  1
01/10/2023  03/10/2023  3
03/10/2023  12/10/2023  8
12/10/2023  19/10/2023  3
19/10/2023  null        1
```